# Wampserver on Windows 8.1 - custom sites don't work

Tags: php, wamp, windows-8.1, wampserver

I've a small problem. I have found similar questions but they differ from mine.
I installed Wampserver. Localhost is working, php is working and Apache is using the 80 port but when I choose my project "test", I have error: *"This webpage is not available"*.
This project contained one file (index.html) with simple code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>Hello!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have never had this error. It has worked on the different computers all the time.

Comment: Is the Apache server pointing to the same folder as your project?

Comment: @jeff no. In Wampserver 2.5 directories are used:

Comment: @jeff sorry, please, repeat your question. It is complete wampserver 2.5. I didn't install php, apache separately

Comment: If your WAMP installation is pointing to c:\WAMP\localhost\www folder but your files are located in c:\myFiles then the Apache server cant find the files. You need to either move your files to where the Apache server expects to find them or alter the path in the Apache config file.

Comment: @jeff thank you for you help, but my files are located in c:\WAMP\localhost\www\test. And I installed another wamp - Open Server. It works

Comment: There is no C:\wamp\localhost\www folder. It is normally C:\wamp\www`. Create a folder = c:\wamp\www\project1 and copy your index.html into that folder. Then enter http://localhost/project1 in the browser address bar.